# Metadata column field value need to be updated

Tags: metadata, update

I want to update a metadata column in sharepoint online library. The column should be updated based on the data in sql db.For example i need to update a field  named student status,i should check what is the status of the student for some x id and  that status need to be updated in sharepoint online document library. Please suggest me the ways.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Develop a custom application (e.g. a .NET Console Application) or use [Microsoft Flow](https://flow.microsoft.com) to create your SQL/SHAREPOINT integration. Flow has connectors for many platforms including SharePoint and SQL Server. Trigger your flow on a schedule or when a student row is created or updated in SQL.

If your SQL Server in installed on-premises then you also need the [Microsoft on-premises data gateway](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/analysis-services/analysis-services-gateway) for Flow to access the data there.

Using Flow might incur additional costs - check the available [pricing plans](https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/) for Microsoft flow.